# fetch boolean core data and filter using if statement

Tags: swift, core-data, boolean, fetch, option-type

in my swift code below the goal is to fetch a boolean value from core data. Once that value is fetched it should be filtered using a if statement. If the value is true is should display a image on the image view and if it is false it should display a different image. I am getting a error at  if let imageData = info[imageNo].bool { stating **Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'**. Don't know what to do next. I added a photo of my core data below

```
    func getBool(imageNo:Int) {
   // first check the array bounds
   let info = helpBool.shareInstance.fetchBool()
    
    print("image count is", info.count)
   if info.count > imageNo {
       
       // check if the data is available
       
       //
       if let imageData = info[imageNo].bool {
           
           
           if true{
               fetchImageView.image = UIImage(named: "true")
           }
           else {
               fetchImageView.image = UIImage(named: "false")
           }
           
       }
       //

}
}


    func fetchBool() -> [OnOff] {
    
  
    var fetchingImage = [OnOff]()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "OnOff")
    
    do {
        
        fetchingImage = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [OnOff]
    } catch {
        print("Error while fetching the image")
    }
    
    return fetchingImage
}

}
```

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRMQS.png)

Comment: Change `if let imageData = info[imageNo].bool` to `if info[imageNo].bool`. You don't need an optional binding here.

Comment: You don't need to use `if let` for something that isn't optional.